# Google App Engine (Python) Image Object Error

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I've extensively searched for an answer to this, and havent come up with anything close. I'm using google app engine to create a form that accepts 2 image files. Then i'd like to take them, get the difference between them, and save that to a blob that i will display beside the two uploaded images.

I'm getting this error "img2 = abs(img1 - img2) TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'Image' and 'Image'" in this chunk of code:

```
img1 = images.Image(blob_key=blob_info.key())
blob_reader = blobstore.BlobReader(blob_info2.key())
img2 = images.Image(blob_key=blob_info2.key())
img3 = abs(img1 - img2)
```

Any help would be appreciated. I tried using the ImageChops difference but it says  so i just took the line from that function and put it directly in my code (being this line: abs(img1 - img2))

Comment: You take the difference of two object references. Looks very strange to me. You should load them first or ...

Comment: I tried that, and got "AttributeError: 'Image' object has no attribute 'load'"

Comment: I was able to switch to loading them from the url, but now i get "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'PixelAccess' and 'PixelAccess'"


    img1 = Image.open(StringIO(urllib2.urlopen(url1).read()))
    img2 = Image.open(StringIO(urllib2.urlopen(url2).read()))
    img2 = abs(img1.load() - img2.load())